# How to make network simulation using React Js

Tags: visnetwork, react-animations, react-vis-network

Would it be possible (is it already) to create a computer network (using appropriate images for nodes: e.g. computer, router, switch, firewall, internet, etc.) and then show the animation how a data packet travels through the network. E.g. data packet (could be the circle) going in animated way along the edges from node1 (e.g. computer) to node2 (e.g. switch) to node3 (e.g. firewall) to node4 (e.g. Internet).

This is the basic network created using vis-network library :

```
// Network.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DataSet, Network } from 'vis-network/standalone/';

const NetworkComponent = () => {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(new DataSet([
    { id: 1, label: 'Node 1' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
    { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
  ]));

  const [edges] = useState(new DataSet([
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
    { from: 2, to: 3 },
    { from: 3, to: 4 },
    { from: 2, to: 3 },
  ]));

  const container = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      nodes: {
        shape: 'circularImage',
        image: 'path/to/your/icon.png', // replace with your icon image path
      },
    };

    const data = {
      nodes: nodes,
      edges: edges,
    };

    const network = new Network(container.current, data, options);

    return () => {
      network.destroy();
    };
  }, [nodes, edges]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={container} style={{ width: '800px', height: '600px' }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NetworkComponent;
```

This is the example related to what i want :
[image: Message sharing in network]
Gif link - [click here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4054499/8289887/041a53d8-18d4-11e5-9363-731673ea1c63.gif)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?